# What language is simple enough for me to make a compiler for as I learn compiler design?

Tags: compiler-construction

I am just finishing my 2nd year of Software Engineering and I thought this summer I'd spend my time learning about compiler design and make my own compiler.

I thought that the easier the language you are making a compiler for, the easier it is for you to actually make the compiler.
I don't know languages that are simple enough for me to make a compiler for. I write in C/C++ and Python and I don't think it'd be a good idea to make a compiler/interpreter for those.

Are there any programming languages that weren't made for "real" use (i.e aren't huge and intimidating) but instead were made to be simple and educational? Something I could use to make a compiler for?
I stumbled across B programming language but I haven't yet really looked into it so I don't know yet.

Comment: You might find [cool](https://theory.stanford.edu/~aiken/software/cool/cool.html) interesting. Stanford has a free-access online compiler course, using COOL as an ongoing example.

Comment: Have a look at Oberon. It's simple, suitable for a single-pass compilation, and have very instructive implementations you can read.

Answer (score 0):

The classic language used to practice writing compilers and interpreters is [Forth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forth_(programming_language)). In particular, parsing and syntax analysis is trivial, so you can focus on the code generation side of things.

Despite its simplicity, Forth is Turing-complete and actively used in the real world (usually on embedded systems).